# Django - How to store two different models in a single database table with same column name

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I have two models country and state.
And the columns which i used for them is as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.
def get_current_datetime_str():
    now = datetime.now()
    return now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

class customer_location(models.Model):
    parent_id=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=100, default='nil')
    added_by=models.CharField(max_length=100, default=1)
    updated_by=models.CharField(max_length=100, default=1)
    created_on=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    updated_on=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        db_table="customer_location"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.created_on = get_current_datetime_str()
        self.updated_on = get_current_datetime_str()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.parent_id = 0
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now i want to set parent id as 0 if a country is entered.
And i want to set the parent id as auto incremented id of country if state is entered.

The main problem i am facing is to store both of them in single table. How can i do that?

Example of Database Schema:
[image: Database Schema]

Comment: The better choice is to migrate these two models into one, and add a `type` columns to mark this record is country or state.

Comment: yes that's a good option but adding a type will modify my database schema, which i don't want :(

Comment: Well, I don't think there's more suitable treatments. Even you find some way to realise it, it maybe really dangerous as that's a **strongly unrecommended** option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `proxy` attribute of the `Meta` class:

```
class CustomerLocation(models.Model):
    parent_id=models.AutoField()
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=100, default='nil')
    added_by=models.CharField(max_length=100, default=1)
    updated_by=models.CharField(max_length=100, default=1)
    created_on=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    updated_on=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table="customer_location"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Country(CustomerLocation):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.created_on = get_current_datetime_str()
        self.updated_on = get_current_datetime_str()
        self.parent_id = 0
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class State(CustomerLocation):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.created_on = get_current_datetime_str()
        self.updated_on = get_current_datetime_str()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```